# Angular - save scope value to variable, but not update it when scope updates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I have something like this:

```
$scope.last_good_configuration = $scope.storage;
```

In $scope.last_good_configuration I keep last good settings.

And when user type in input bad value, for example too big integer i want to do:

```
$scope.storage = $scope.last_good_configuration;
```

But my $scope.last_good_configuration is all the time the same as $scope.storage. How to stop updating $scope.last_good_configuration? I have to evaluate my scope somehow?

Comment: we are missing informations to help you...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make a copy or clone of the original object. Angular has a built in method for this: [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy).

```
$scope.last_good_configuration = angular.copy($scope.storage);


//Edits must be at least 6 characters workaround
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a new object using [`angular.copy()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) so when you make changes to `storage` it won't affect `last_good_configuration`

```
$scope.last_good_configuration = angular.copy($scope.storage);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since objects are passed by reference, you need to create a *new* object to store default configuration in. Otherwise, when you modify `$scope.last_good_configuration` it also affects `$scope.storage` since they both point to the same object.

Use [`angular.extend`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend) method which will copy all properties from `$scope.storage` into the new object `{}`:

```
$scope.last_good_configuration = angular.extend({}, $scope.storage);
```

UPD. I totally forgot about dedicated [`angular.copy`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) which is probably more appropriate in this case, especially is `$scope.storage` has nested object structure: `angualar.extend` will make a shallow copy, in this case you should use `angular.copy` (see Satpal answer).